# SQL reporting on rolling quarters

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting

This is sample data that Im using.
Based on this data, I will need to create rolling quarter reports. In other words, monthly reports looking back 3 months. The issue is that I will need to report averges and sums. Below is the format of the output Im looking for.

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to implement this?
Should I do the calculations on quarterly basis or should I do them on monthly basis?

Currently the process is being done in Excel, so I'm actually working with tables that do not have relationships yet.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Brute force solution

```
WITH MonthData AS (
    SELECT (YEAR(Date) - 2000) * 12 + MONTH(Date) AS MonthNumber
          ,Count1
          ,Count2
    FROM Table
)
,QuarterData AS (
    SELECT MAX(MonthNumber) AS MonthNumber
          ,SUM(Count1)/COUNT(1) AS MeanCount1
          ,SUM(Count2)/COUNT(1) AS MeanCount2
          ,SUM(Count1) AS SumCount1
          ,SUM(Count2) AS SumCount2
    FROM MonthData
    GROUP BY MonthNumber / 3 
  UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(MonthNumber)
          ,SUM(Count1)/COUNT(1)
          ,SUM(Count2)/COUNT(1)
          ,SUM(Count1)
          ,SUM(Count2)
    FROM MonthData
    GROUP BY (MonthNumber + 1) / 3   
  UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(MonthNumber)
          ,SUM(Count1)/COUNT(1)
          ,SUM(Count2)/COUNT(1)
          ,SUM(Count1)
          ,SUM(Count2)
    FROM MonthData
    GROUP BY (MonthNumber + 2) / 3 
)
SELECT DATEADD(month, MonthNumber, '20000101') AS Period
      ,MeanCount1
      ,MeanCount2
      ,SumCount1
      ,SumCount2
FROM QuarterData
```